# How to filter External List programmatically?

Tags: .net, list, filter, external, connectivity

I've developed custom Business Data Connectivity solution using .NET Assembly Connector. It does have Comparison type filter for Finder method.

I can now create External List and use Data Source Filter from Edit view - it works.
I can also add Business Data Connectivity filter web part, connect it to the external list - it works.

My question: how to filter the external list programmatically?

I don't want to enter value in edit list view or in Select External Items dialog of BDC filter web part.
I want the value to be calculated on page load, for example, value = web site name,

In other words, is that possible to implement Business Data Connectivity filter web part yourself? it should work once, I don't want to change filter value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my findings.

First, I've prepared Elements.xml and Schema.xml for my External List by importing List from wsp package as described in http://blog.voltje.be/2010/07/23/deploying-an-external-list-using-visual-studio-2010/comment-page-1/

Hopefully, Schema.xml does contain required filter with value, like that:

```
<View DisplayName="My View name" ...>
   <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
   <Method Name="ReadList">
   <Filter Name="My Comparison filter" Value="My Value" />
   </Method>
   <Query>
```

.....

Then I've tried two ways:

1) using SPView.SetViewXml
(as described in http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.ru/2011/11/sharepoint-2010-update-default-list.html)

It does not seem to work for external list :((
I mean when importing the xml with view, the value of the filter is not set, for unknown reason.

2) by using List Instance based on the above Elements.xml and Schema.xml.
It works just fine, new list is create with filter and value.
The fist way would be much more better for me...